# LSC check if attribute is not null

Tags: java, openldap, lsc

I'm using `LSC` to sync `OpenLDAP` to AD `DS`. I need to sync two attributes from `OpenLDAP` to one (`proxyaddresses`) in AD DS, with "smtp:" added before attribute. Attribute need to be senced only when it is not null in `OpenLDAP`.

```
<dataset>   <name>proxyAddresses</name>             <!-- Add proxyAddresses from employeeType and employeeNumber and mail -->
        <policy>FORCE</policy>
        <forceValues>
    <string>js:(srcBean.getDatasetFirstValueById("employeeType") != null ? (("smtp:") + (srcBean.getDatasetFirstValueById("employeeType"))) : null) </string>
    </forceValues>
    </dataset>
```

Above is not working. When attribute employeeType is null in OpenLDAP, it is syncing only "smtp:".

How to sync attribute with prefix, but only when it is not null?

Tired changing attribute from OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution is to make rjs script for all three attributes:

```js
<dataset>
        <name>proxyAddresses</name>
        <policy>FORCE</policy>
        <forceValues>
        <string>
        <![CDATA[rjs:
                var number = "smtp:" + srcBean.getDatasetValuesById("employeeNumber");
                var str = number.toString().toLowerCase();
                var emptystr = str.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                if (srcBean.getDatasetValuesById("employeeNumber") != null && !srcBean.getDatasetValuesById("employeeNumber").isEmpty()) {
                    emptystr;
               } else {
                    null;
        
                }
        ]]>     
        </string>       
        <string>
        <![CDATA[rjs:       
                var type = "smtp:" + srcBean.getDatasetValuesById("employeeType");
                var str2 = type.toString().toLowerCase();
                var emptystr2 = str2.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                if (srcBean.getDatasetValuesById("employeeType") != null && !srcBean.getDatasetValuesById("employeeType").isEmpty()) {
                    emptystr2;
               } else {
                    null;
                }
        ]]>
        </string>
        <string>
        <![CDATA[rjs:
                var umail = "SMTP:" + srcBean.getDatasetValuesById("mail");
                var str3 = umail.toString();
                var emptystr3 = str3.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                if (srcBean.getDatasetValuesById("mail") != null && !srcBean.getDatasetValuesById("mail").isEmpty()) {
                    emptystr3;
                } else {
                    null;
                }
        ]]>
        </string>
        </forceValues>
        </dataset>
```